iis return 404 when url has [] cause next.js dynamic routes chunk load error
I host a next.js app on iis server, and any urls with [] (%5B, %5D) return a 404 error which includes the generated js files for any dynamic page
for example there is file at  /_next/static/chunks/pages/Category/[category]-someid.js
/_next/static/chunks/pages/Category/%5Bcategory%5D-someid.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

This is a similar problem https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/54008, but it is with docker not iis.
I am able to get other type of chunk files, just not those dynamic routes chunk with []. how to enable iis accept special characters?
I have set allowDoubleEscaping= true

So which version of Next.js are you using? And you are using iisnode?

yea I am using iisnode, and urlrewrite. and version "next": "13.5.2".  it works fine at local tho.


You might upgrade to at least Next.js 13.5.4, as the GitHub issue you linked indicates. That's a bug in Next.js itself, so applicable to all scenarios, not merely Docker hosting.
You might give up the out of maintenance iisnode (and URL rewrite rules) and switch to just HttpPlatformHandler

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\node.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.20.1\node.exe" arguments=".\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next start">
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
                <environmentVariable name="NODE_ENV" value="Production" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

In this way, things like Dynamic Routes start to work properly. More details can be found in
https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-next-js-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

unfortunately after upgrading to the latest next.js 14.x  still having problem with it, but error code change from 404 to 500. I might try using httpplatformhandler later on.

Upgrading Next.js to the latest version helped me.

You can also try to change the registry file like
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET] 
"VerificationCompatibility"=dword:00000001 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters] 
"AllowRestrictedChars"=dword:00000001


not sure who downvote your solution, but that did not work.

I've re-edited my answer, please try again.
